# How to properly tune network for Turn Server in a WebRTC application?

Tags: webrtc, turn

I'm working on a WebRTC solution for audio/picture comunication and I'm a bit concerned about the lack of bandwidth control when two Peers in LAN are communicating.

Basically I want to be able to prioritize and pre-allocate bandwidth on my switch for WebRTC calls. But I couldn't see a proper way of filtering the packets when they are in a P2P call.

Also, I don't want to decode the packet to do that, because of the possible delay caused by this operation.

I hope you guys can show me a proper way or just tell me if my teorical solution could work.

I'm not 100% sure about the idea I'm planning to test, because I don't know how TURN server works internally.

But here is the idea:

[image]

And what I dont know is: **Is it possible to make 2 turn servers know each other? Would they work like a 2 layer proxy between callers? If yes, could you please show me what I have to do to make it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install a internal proxy server to the external turn server and prioritize the proxy on your lan.

(answering my own question after realizing the solution was easier than I thought)